# How to read Http response from flutter?

Tags: http, flutter, response

I'm trying to read reponse from HTTP in flutter but I didnt read.
I posted the request. Can anyone know, what is wrong ?

```
final http.Client client;

Future<http.Response> post(
  Uri uri, {
    Map<String, dynamic> postParams,
    String accessToken,
  }) async {
log.info(uri.toString());
log.info('postParams: ${postParams?.toString()}');

///Encode map to bytes
String jsonString = json.encode(postParams);
List<int> bodyBytes = utf8.encode(jsonString);

Map headers = {
  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
};


final response = await client
    .post(
  uri,
  body: bodyBytes,
  headers: headers,
)
    .timeout(Duration(seconds: 120));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality as follow

1.install `http` package and import it as follow

```
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

2. Create an instance of `http` or `http.Client` as you did

   ```
   final http.Client _client = http.Client();
   ```
3. Send the request to server as follow

   ```
   var url = 'https://example.com/store/.....'; 

   final Map<String, dynamic> data= {"name":"John Doe", "email":"johndoe@email.com"};

   final Map<String, String> _headers = {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Accept": "application/json",
    };

   var response = await _client.post(url, body:data, headers:_headers);
   ```
4. Then you can read the response as

   ```
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      var decoded = json.decode(response.body);
      print(decoded);

      // The Rest of code 
    }
   ```

Comment: I guess problem  in here: 
final response = await client
    .post(
  uri,
  body: bodyBytes,
  headers: headers,
)
    .timeout(Duration(seconds: 120));
}

Comment: Can you tell me what type of data you want send to server ?

Comment: {name:"bla bla",surname:"bla bla"} like that

Comment: I have these 4 steps already, but still same. Thanks for help.

Comment: `final http.Client client`,  here you didn't initialize the `client`, step 2

Comment: yes I did, initialize. 
I get an error when I try to send headers. I have to send headers in post. Any solution?

Comment: I have to send headers. If I can not send , I have 400 Bad Request. Any solution?

Comment: I added the headers in the requrest, If you have `400 Bad Request` you need to check your server route for the request method, and the expected data and also check your url

Comment: I didn't get you, Can you explain why you want something like you mentioned? `flutter http` package requires a `Map<String, String>` in it's post request headers

Comment: I personally use `flutter dio` to communicate with the server

Comment: Thanks for help. I wrote Map<String, String> and I solved. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad it helped you