# Android Studio Variables window does not show `body`, but I can call it

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, http

I am using `http` lib to make `http` request in my `Flutter app`
`import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`
And when I was looking for `response body`. I was puzzled that I couldn't find it in first glance. And spending couple hours I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409417/how-to-read-http-response-from-flutter)

Here is my `Android Studio`

```
Android Studio 4.0.2
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6821437, built on September 9, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart, io.flutter
```

**Problem:**
I don't see `body` in the `Variables` window here
[image: No body]

**Question**
Is it bug in the `Android Studio`?

Comment: Hat the debugger shows you is the internal view on an object and it's fields. When you access an object you don't use the internal but the external view and therefore naming of fields can be different and of course the can be methods that return data that is not directly related to a field. Therefore you should ignore the debugger view and instead read the API documentation and check the autocomplete function in the code editor.

Comment: New knowledge. Thank you very much